# El valor no se inserta en el campo dentro de tabla SQL

Tags: php, mysql

La tabla consta de los siguientes campos: `id`, `usuario`, `contra`, `prueba_uno`, `prueba_dos`, `prueba_tres`, `prueba_4`. Una vez que el usuario inicia sesión puede realizar 4 examenes diferentes.

Este código tiene que poder escribir en la tabla la calificación del examen para el usuario correspondiente. Cuando ejecuto el código no aparece ningún mensaje de error.

La página se está quedando en blanco, compruebo la tabla y no se escribió ningún valor. Sospecho que es porque `prueba_uno`, `prueba_dos`, `prueba_tres` y `prueba_4` tienen valor de `NULL` por defecto, aunque ignoro si no sea posible escribir en campos con `Null = yes` y `default = NULL`.

```
<?php
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $calificacion = $_POST['calificacion'];

    $conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','pruebas');
    $agregar_calificacion = "
        INSERT INTO usuarios
            (prueba_uno)
        VALUES
            ('".$calificacion."');
        WHERE
            usuario = '".$usuario."'
    ";
    mysqli_query($conexion, $agregar_calificacion);

    $conexion->close();
?>
```

Comment: tiene registros tu tabla? el error parece estar en la siguiente linea **('".$calificacion."');** pues estas terminando el sql(por el punto y coma) sin embargo despues estas utilizando el where. Ademas lo que debes hacer es un update no un insert.

Comment: Si, solamente tiene un registro, el cual quedaria asi:
```id = 1, usuario = pepito, contra = hola, prueba_uno = NULL, prueba_dos = NULL, prueba_tres = NULL, prueba_cuatro = NULL```. Gracias, ya quite el punto y la coma pero aun sigue sin registrar el valor.

Comment: como te digo debes hacer un update no un insert

Comment: Okay, o sea que nada mas borro en donde dice insert y le pongo update? Asi le hice y aun sigue sin poner la calificacion en la tabla

Comment: Gracias ya lo logre

Answer (score 1):

El `INSERT INTO` es para cuando la tabla está completamente vacía, por ende, cuando ya manejas datos dentro de la tabla, entonces lo que requieres es **modificación**, por ende en lugar de usar `INSERT INTO` debes usar `UPDATE`. Tambien debes verificar si es necesario restringir el dato con tu cláusula `where`.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que quieres actualizar un dato, así que la sentencia que deberías utilizar en vez de `INSERT` sería `UPDATE`, de lo contrario si quieres insertar el dato deberías de quitar el `WHERE`.